# Toolbar home up button pointing left in RTL

Tags: android, android-toolbar, right-to-left

Home up button in RTL is pointing left on Android 5.1(API 22) and lower:
[image]

But on Android 6.0(API 23) everything is ok and it's pointing right.

[image]

How to solve that?

Comment: did u try to put an arrow poiting right on `/drawable-ldrtl/` folder? (that is folder for right-to-left languages (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Comment: not, yet because I'm not replacing standard arrow. I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  your `style.xml` put:

```
 <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_arrow_back</item>
```

And create a `drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17` folder in `res` and put proper drawable (RTL drawable).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**

You can generate duplicates and keep versions in proper directories (e.g. drawable-ar).

**Solution 2 (My Fav)**

Fortunately, there is an easy way around. You just need to use styles.

```
values/styles.xml
<style name="MirroredImage" />

values-ar/styles.xml
<style name="MirroredImage">
    <item name="android:scaleX">-1</item>
</style>

my_layout.xml
<ImageView
    style="@style/MirroredImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_to_be_mirrored"/>
```